# Dynamic cast to enum using SimpleFramework

Tags: java, enums, simple-framework

I have an XML String with an attribute that contains integer value:

```
<item status="2" />
```

There is also `Simple Framework` class that describes this `item`:

```
@Root
public static class Item {

    @Attribute(name="status")
    private int status;

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

}
```

Unserialization works well, however I want to be able to change `int` type to the defined `enum` type.

```
public enum Status {
    OK(0), PENDING(1), ERROR(2);

    BetStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

So with a quick modification:

```
@Root
public static class Item {

    @Attribute(name="status")
    private Status status;

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

}
```

However now I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 2 is not a constant in com.my.package.Status
```

Is it possible to cast `int` this way during unserialization ?

I bet I have to add some magic method to my `Status` class.

**Solution:**

According to `Reimeus` answer I leaved `int` type for `status` attribute and I modified just `Item` class with:

```
@Root
public static class Item {

    @Attribute(name="status")
    private int status;

    public Status getStatus() {
        return Status.getByOrdinal(status);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps by iterating through the types:

```
public enum Status {
    OK(0), PENDING(1), ERROR(2);

    private int status;

    Status(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public static Status getByOrdinal(int ordinal) {
        for (final Status element : EnumSet.allOf(Status.class)) {
            if (element.ordinal() == ordinal) {
                return element;
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown status type: " + ordinal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Combine the `getByOrdinal` method provided by Reimeus with an additional setter in `Item` that takes an int.

```
public void setStatus(int status)
{
    this.status = Status.getByOrdinal(status);
}
```

Comment: I have already did it - without setter (because of Item class read-only policy), just getter. I have described it in the bottom of my question. ;)

Comment: That edit wasn't visible while I was typing this up. However I'd still do the `getByOrdinal` on set rather than on get in order to have any failure caused by an invalid ordinal number occur as early as possible, and as close to what is causing the error as possible (easier to debug).

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would guess so as it's accepted convention to do so. I would certainly try it first to see if it works, or you can look up the documentation to check.